# getting list of aws lambda functions from within the code of a lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a lambda function within AWS based off the clear-lambda-storage application at . There is code that is as follows:

```
from argparse import Namespace
from clear_lambda_storage import remove_old_lambda_versions


def clear_lambda_storage(event, context):
    remove_old_lambda_versions(Namespace(token_key_id=None, token_secret=None, regions=None, profile=None, num_to_keep=3, function_names=["insertName"]))
    return "Successful clean!  ✅"
```

With the `function_names` argument I want to have a list of names of all the lambda functions in the account - is there any way I can do this besides manually hardcoding them (so that if a new lambda function is added, the list is updated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the SDK. IN ptyhon, this is boto3, and so one of these commands, probably https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.list_functions

Comment: but this returns a maximum of 50 functions per call - to get all the lambda functions would I need to keep calling it multiple times?

Comment: Not quite - you need to use Pagination. The `NextMarker (string) ` tag gives you the ability to page along the results. It technically is multiple calls, but can be done with the same client declaration in your code.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by same client declaration? do you have an example

Comment: With the SDKs (ie boto3) you declare a client for connecting to a given service. `fn_client = boto3.client("lambda")` as long as you are not re-declaring a client, you can make multiple `fn_client.list_functions()` calls with the NextMarker token as a starting point in order to page through all of them. Doing so in a Loop is one method.